# Using NIntegrate inside NDSolve

Tags: mathematica-8

I am trying to numerically solve a partial differential equation, where the inhomogeneous term is an integral of another function. Something like this:

NDSolve[{D[f[x, y], x] == NIntegrate[h[x,y+y2],{y2, x, y}],f[0,y] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y,0,1}]

where h[x,y] is a well known function previously defined.
But it seems that Mathematica does not know how to evaluate the integral.

I do not use Mathematica too often, so I am sure there is a simple solution to this.
Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear from the question, but I had a similar problem and the solution in my case was to follow the advice from the [wolfram forums](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/May/msg00815.html) to put the integral in an extra function and force real input.

So in your case this would be

```
integral[x_Real,y_Real] := NIntegrate[h[x,y+y2],{y2, x, y}];
NDSolve[{D[f[x, y], x] == integral[x,y], f[0,y] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y,0,1}]
```